# Python re module - Unexpected behaviour with \b and '-'

Tags: python, regex

I was testing (using [*pythex*](http://pythex.org/)) a regex match between

```
re.compile('''
              [ ]?
              (?P<element> [a-zA-Z])         
              [ ]+
              (?P<x_axis> \b-?[0-9]+[.][0-9]+\b)  # the first '\b' seems to be
                                                  # causing this issue
              ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

and string `' C -1.97046278'`. This lead to no matches being found.

Then, when I tried removing `\b` *re* found the match for the aforementioned string.

Is the syntax incorrect? Cause I've been reading the documentation for *re* and haven't found any mention of  this.

Care to explain this behaviour for me?

Answer (score 1):

`\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character. Both space and `-` are non-word characters, so `\b` will not match between them.

Word characters are letters, digits, and underscore. Non-word characters are everything else.

Also, you need to use a raw string delimited by `r''' ... '''`, so that escape sequences like `\b` will be passed to the `re` module, not processed as string escapes.

Comment: This is only part of the issue - as OP doesn't use raw string notation `\b` is a literal backspace character.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues here:

- Word boundaries `\b` are *ambiguous* as their meaning is context dependent. In this case, if there is a `-` before the digit, `\b-?[0-9]` will only match if there is a word char before the `-`. You need to place `\b` *after*  `-?`. If you remove this `\b`, your regex will start matching the digits in any context, and  I suspect you still want to match whole words only.
- You need to declare the regex with a *raw string literal* so as `\b` was treated as a word boundary and not as a backspace char.

Use

```
import re
r=re.compile(r'''
              [ ]?
              (?P<element> [a-zA-Z])         
              [ ]+
              (?P<x_axis> -?\b[0-9]+[.][0-9]+\b)  # the first '\b' seems to be
                                                  # causing this issue
              ''', re.VERBOSE)
s = ' C -1.97046278'
print(r.findall(s))
```

See an [online Python demo](http://ideone.com/RnUiNd)

Answer (score 0):

You will certainly need:

```
re.compile(r'''
              [ ]?
              (?P<element> [a-zA-Z])         
              [ ]+
              (?P<x_axis> \b-?[0-9]+[.][0-9]+\b)  # the first '\b' seems to be
                                                  # causing this issue
              ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Note the `r` in the `compile()` call.